# Как узнать, был ли тип уже объявлен ранее?

Tags: c, typedef

Допустим, есть такой код:

```
typedef int i32;
```

Как узнать, был ли тип `i32` уже объявлен ранее? Т. е. что-то типа `#ifdef` только для `typedef`.

Comment: Препроцессор точно не сможет для typedef. Но если объявить тип через define, то сможет.

Comment: А зачем вам может это понадобиться? Это случаем не проблема XY?

Comment: @VTT, ну, на самом деле, вопрос теоретический.

Comment: Ну в теории повторное объявление алиаса типа стало доступно только начиная с C11. А так будете получать предупреждение `-Wtypedef-redefinition`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никак не узнать.

Если дальновидный автор кода предвидит необходимость такой проверки в будущем, он обычно сопровождает определения типов определением дополнительного макро. Так, например, стандартный заголовочный файл `<stdbool.h>` содержит определение макро `__bool_true_false_are_defined` со значением `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Есть метод двойной компиляции, знаю как в **Linux** через **Makefile** это делать. Сначала компилируется простой файл с **typedef**. Затем проверяется код ошибки компиляции, и задаётся `#define TYPEREDEFINIED`.

```
Makefile :
main.o : main.c main.h
 ..TAB..: if gcc checktypedef.c &> /dev/null ; then  ; else OPTIONFORGCC = -DTYPEREDEFINIED ; fi
 ..TAB..: gcc OPTIONFORGCC main.c
..

checktypedef.c :
# include <все заголовки из main>
typedef unsigned char BYTE ;

main.c :
# include <все заголовки>
# ifdef TYPEREDEFINIED
# error Опять!
# endif
```

Comment: Есть предположение что кода ошибки не будет, даже с -pedantic, -std= надо обьявлять и -Wtypedef-redefinition

Answer (score 0):

Возможно обьявить все используемые хеадеры в одном файле `test.c` например, потом:

```
gcc -E test.c | grep "int32my"
```

и смотрим результат :)

Comment: ? Это не легальный способ

Comment: Что есть 'легальный' способ ? что бы понять что есть 'не легальный' ? :) Если интересует результат, то это работает.

Comment: Легальный способ это такой который даеться авторами языками как официальный и рабочий. Ваш код на пример требует вызова команды в compile-time что не так то легко. Кроме того он например сработает на тип "__int32my_internal".

Comment: То есть этот способ работает как попало